# add content inline next to an input-group and have them not wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input-group that I use for executing user queries.  I want to have two anchors next to the input-group that are aligned with the input (they are for other functionality, however).  I don't want them ever to go to the next line, as they must stay next to the input control.

[Here is what it should always look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhh1.png)

The input and magnifying glass icon are the input-group, and the email and save icon are my elements I want next to it.  I would prefer to not use columns, as I end up with extra space with the 12 column granularity, but I can live with it.

As soon as I resize the browser, smaller, the icons drop down to the next row.

Regarless of my current implementation, what would be the best way to get my desired result (i.e. these two icons next to my input-group, regardless of browser sizing)?

Here is what I am currently doing:

```css
// keeps the icons from floating up
.user-data-button-bar {
  padding-top: 7px;
  min-width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="input-group pull-left col-xs-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
  <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="user-data-button-bar col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
  <span class="" ng-controller="UserDataButtonsController as vm">
    <a>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>
    </a>
    <a>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: might be that the // comment is not valid (`/* css comment */`) and that `col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10`would be more appropriate than 11

Comment: This is not answering your question but you don't have to use col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 this is exactly the same to just say col-xs-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table layout for this since the `input-group` component already uses that format as well. You can utilize this with or without columns and inside other components.

**Example CSS**

```
.user-data-button-bar {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.user-data-button-bar .user-data-button-controls {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80px;
}

.user-data-button-bar .user-data-button-controls span {
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 2;
    padding-left: 22.5px;
}
```

**Working Examples:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.user-data-button-bar {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: 15px solid #337ab7;
}
.user-data-button-bar .user-data-button-controls {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
}
.user-data-button-bar .user-data-button-controls span {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 2;
  padding-left: 22.5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<h3 class="text-center">0 Columns</h3>
<div class="user-data-button-bar">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="user-data-button-controls">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Inside a Panel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="text-center">1 Column</h3>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="text-center">2 Columns</h3>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="text-center">3 Columns</h3>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="user-data-button-bar">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                         </button>
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="user-data-button-controls">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome!  Minor tweaking gave me just what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome and don't forget to mark your questions as answered if they are.